# Could the u in e.g. aufero be related to the u in Mycenaean a-pu-do-ke?

Tags: etymology, greek, mycenaean, vowel

I came across this Mycenaen word when I was trapped in a Wikipaedia chain:

> the verbal augment is almost entirely absent from Mycenaean Greek with only one known exception, [image] (), a-pe-do-ke (PY Fr 1184), but even that appears elsewhere without the augment, as [image] (), a-pu-do-ke (KN Od 681). — https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mycenaean_Greek

I presume this is the third person singular aorist from *ἀποδίδωμι*, "he gave". Perhaps ἀπο and Latin *a(b(s))* in *aufero* etc. are related. Is there any conexion at all between the Mycenaean u and the Latin u here? My guess would be coincidence, and *a(b(s))* and ἀπο might not be related at all (I believe ὑπό is related, at least), but who knows?

---

P.S. I see Linear B in Firefox, although I now see that they won't show up in Chrome. Do you have a Linear B font installed? You could get the Aegean fonts here: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d

Comment: Not ἀποδοκέω but ἀποδίδωμι, I believe (aor. ἀπέδωκε). As for *au-*, it's not at all clear that it's related to *abs-*.

Comment: @TKR: Ah, that's alos possible. But why do you think it isn't from ἀποδοκέω?

Comment: Because (a) I seem to remember those particular forms, (b) ἀποδοκέω is much less common than ἀποδίδωμι, (c) the Linear B tablets are mostly about transactions, and (d) impf. ἁπεδόκεε would not have been contracted so should be spelled *-ke-e*.

Comment: @TKR: Ah, I seemed to remember all of those words were all related, but then L&S mention only ὐπό, not ἀπο, under "ab". // All excellent points a–d. Any one is enough to convince me. As to d), are you sure? I can think of two questions that would have to be answered by "yes": was the -e- always part of the stem of δοκέω in earlier Greek such as Mycenaean? Did the Mycenaeans always write Ce-e out in full, did they never omit a (final) repeated vowel in writing?

Comment: Somewhat related old question on Linguistics SE: http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/why-does-b-differ-between-l-offero-and-l-aufero

Comment: All that Greek shows up as just empty boxes in my browser, both here and in Wikipedia. I assume you didn't mean to have eight identical boxes (but I never was strong with Greek so it's hard to judge). Could you add them as images?

Comment: I believe the answer to both your (d) questions is yes. δοκέω is an -eie- verb formed on the o-grade, like e.g. φορέω; these always have the -ε-, which is part of the formation going back to PIE. As for whether there are examples of a repeated vowel being omitted in Linear B, I can't say for certain that this doesn't happen, but it isn't usual: e.g. we have e-ke-e for later ἔχειν, and other such examples.

Comment: @TKR OK that all makes sense!

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta I see Linear B in Firefox, although I now see that the characters won't show up in Chrome. Do you have a Linear B font installed? You could get the Aegean fonts here: http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/

Comment: @Cerberus None of Chrome, Firefox or IE shows the characters. Firefox has numbers in the boxes, but that's of little help. Perhaps I don't have a font, and actually I couldn't even have the fonts on all devices I use. It'd be better if viewing the content didn't depend on having exotic fonts. (I might install those fonts at some point for fun. But not all will.)

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Yes, if you don't have the font installed, it won't show up anywhere on your system. It took me a while and it looks somewhat ugly, but I have added inline images. I also recommend the Egyptian and cuneiform fonts.

Comment: There was a flag to close this as off-topic. Although the site name is Latin, [we have decided to allow questions about some forms of Greek](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/q/218/79), and this question is therefore on topic. This might be on-topic on some other SE sites as well, but it does not make it off-topic here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The υ of ἀπύ (also attested in Arcado-Cypriot, which is the most conservative group of Greek dialects and often shows similarities with Mycenaean) is a secondary development within the Greek dialects, and not inherited from Indo-European. This is shown by many cognates which reflect *o*, e.g. Hitt. *appā*, Skt. *apa*, Russ. *po*. So it's unlikely to be related to anything in Latin.

The change of *ab-* to *au-*, if that's what it is, seems to be a Latin- (or Italic-?) specific sound change before *f*: *au-fero, au-fugio*. However, it is also possible that this *au-* reflects a separate Indo-European morpheme *h₂eu-* 'away', and is not related to *ab-* at all.